# Colocar setas para mudar por cima do carrossel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boas,

Eu precisava de colocar as setas do meu carrossel que servem para mudar de imagem por cima do carrossel desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ja usei o z-index e tentei mudar os display mas não fica em cima da imagem.

Aqui vai o meu codigo:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.botao {
    z-index: 2;
    position: inherit;
    display: 
}

.slideshow {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rio Lis</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./normalize.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slideshow">
      <img class="mySlides" src="./imagens/1014033.jpg">
      <img class="mySlides" src="./imagens/thumb-1920-1000923.jpg">
      <img class="mySlides" src="./imagens/thumb-1920-926492.jpg">
    
      <button class="botaoesquerda botao" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="botaodireira botao" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara um opção é colocar `position:relative` no *container* do *slider* e usar `position:absolute` nos btns para poder alinhar com `top/left/right`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja o resultado**

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.botao {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 30px;
}

.botaodireira {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}

.slideshow {
  /* z-index: -1; */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.placecage.com/600/100">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.placecage.com/600/100">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.placecage.com/600/100">

  <button class="botaoesquerda botao" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="botaodireira botao" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

**OBS:** se vc colocar `z-index:-1` no *container* do *slider* vc não vai conseguir clicar nos botões que estão dentro desse *container*. Na verdade não vi necessidade de usar esse  `z-index:-1` então  deixei comentado no CSS

Answer (score 0):

Todos os elementos são ou "posicionados" ou "estáticos". Posicionados são todos que possuem `position: relative`, `absolute` etc (qualquer position exceto `static`). Elementos sem uma position declarada ou com `position: static` serão estáticos e seguirão o fluxo da página.

Sabendo disso, perceba que *itens posicionados sempre estarão "na frente" dos itens estáticos*. O z-index tem por objetivo *apenas ordenar itens posicionados*. Ele de nada serve para itens estáticos.

No seu caso, os botões herdaram a posição estática do slideshow, e portanto foram empurrados para baixo, seguindo o fluxo da página. A forma mais simples de lidar com isso é dar-lhes `position: absolute`, e não se esqueça de dar ao slideshow `position: relative` para ancoragem.

Compreender o posicionamento é vital para um web developer, portanto, [não deixe de ler sobre o assunto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning).